# sed operation being overwritten in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, sed, dockerfile

I have in interesting issue where, in my Dockerfile, I'm running an inline sed command in a `RUN` directive. I can watch the STDOUT of the build and see the sed command is correct and successful however, once the image is built and run, the file is not modified. This leads me to believe that another layer is overwriting the one from that `RUN` declaration, but I don't *think* that a subsequent directive in my Dockerfile would do that. Here is the Dockerfile (the ping was to speed up startup to troubleshoot). Notice that I commented out the `VOLUME` directive just to see if that was interfering somehow (like in this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40074498/sed-inline-replacement-not-working-from-dockerfile), even though my `RUN` is before the `VOLUME`. I feel like I'm missing something basic, but after banging my head on the desk for 2 weeks, I need help. :-)

```
FROM alpine:3.6
RUN apk add --no-cache maven git
WORKDIR /build/
RUN git clone https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-repository-helm.git \
    && cd nexus-repository-helm \
    && mvn clean package



FROM    centos:centos7
LABEL MAINTAINER=[...]

ENV NEXUS_VERSION=3.12.1-01
ARG NEXUS_DOWNLOAD_URL=https://download.sonatype.com/nexus/3/nexus-${NEXUS_VERSION}-unix.tar.gz
ARG NEXUS_DOWNLOAD_SHA256_HASH=8f3137471cdb002b6cf9d1874bbddb6ad280d4d7a492e363cfc5f54fbd45b5d9

RUN yum install -y \
  curl tar java-1.8.0-openjdk \
  && yum clean all


# configure nexus runtime
ENV SONATYPE_DIR=/opt/sonatype
ENV NEXUS_HOME=${SONATYPE_DIR}/nexus \
  NEXUS_DATA=/nexus-data \
  NEXUS_CONTEXT='' \
  SONATYPE_WORK=${SONATYPE_DIR}/sonatype-work \
  DOCKER_TYPE='docker'

# install nexus
RUN mkdir -p ${NEXUS_HOME} \
  && curl --fail --silent --location --retry 3 \
    ${NEXUS_DOWNLOAD_URL} \
  | gunzip \
  | tar x -C ${NEXUS_HOME} --strip-components=1 nexus-${NEXUS_VERSION} \
  && chown -R root:root ${NEXUS_HOME}

COPY --from=0 \
      /build/nexus-repository-helm/target/nexus-repository-helm-0.0.1.jar \
  ${NEXUS_HOME}/system/org/sonatype/nexus/plugins/nexus-repository-helm/0.0.1/nexus-repository-helm-0.0.1.jar

# configure nexus
RUN sed -e '/^nexus-context/ s:$:${NEXUS_CONTEXT}:' -i ${NEXUS_HOME}/etc/nexus-default.properties

RUN sed -e '/<feature prerequisite/i\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ <feature prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-repository-helm<\/feature>' -e '/<\/features>/i \ \ \ \ <feature name="nexus-repository-helm" description="org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-repository-helm" version="0.0.1">\n        <details>org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-repository-helm<\/details>\n        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus.plugins/nexus-repository-helm/0.0.1<\/bundle>\n    <\/feature>' \
    ${NEXUS_HOME}/system/org/sonatype/nexus/assemblies/nexus-core-feature/${NEXUS_VERSION}/nexus-core-feature-${NEXUS_VERSION}-features.xml

RUN useradd -r -u 200 -m -c "nexus role account" -d ${NEXUS_DATA} -s /bin/false nexus \
  && mkdir -p ${NEXUS_DATA}/etc ${NEXUS_DATA}/log ${NEXUS_DATA}/tmp ${SONATYPE_WORK} \
  && ln -s ${NEXUS_DATA} ${SONATYPE_WORK}/nexus3 \
  && chown -R nexus:nexus ${NEXUS_DATA}

#VOLUME ${NEXUS_DATA}

EXPOSE 8081

WORKDIR ${NEXUS_HOME}

ENV INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME="/usr/bin/java"
ENV INSTALL4J_ADD_VM_PARAMS="-Xms1200m -Xmx1200m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2g -Djava.util.prefs.userRoot=${NEXUS_DATA}/javaprefs"

USER nexus

CMD ["ping", "localhost"]
#CMD ["bin/nexus", "run"]
```

Here is the STDOUT of the build (Step 11 is the sed operation):

```
$ docker build -t nexus:local .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  9.625MB
Step 1/8 : FROM alpine:3.6
 ---> 77144d8c6bdc
Step 2/8 : RUN apk add --no-cache maven git
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 06ea90323059
Step 3/8 : WORKDIR /build/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 883f7001e5e7
Step 4/8 : RUN git clone https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-repository-helm.git     && cd nexus-repository-helm     && mvn clean package
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8916c43cbca0
Step 5/8 : FROM sonatype/nexus3
 ---> 292674e848ae
Step 6/8 : LABEL MAINTAINER=[...]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ba1dedda1d61
Step 7/8 : COPY --from=0       /build/nexus-repository-helm/target/nexus-repository-helm-0.0.1.jar   ${NEXUS_HOME}/system/org/sonatype/nexus/plugins/nexus-repository-helm/0.0.1/nexus-repository-helm-0.0.1.jar
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d6c2db5babd8
Step 8/8 : RUN sed -e '/<feature prerequisite/i\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ <feature prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-repository-helm<\/feature>' -e '/<\/features>/i \ \ \ \ <feature name="nexus-repository-helm" description="org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-repository-helm" version="0.0.1">\n        <details>org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-repository-helm<\/details>\n        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus.plugins/nexus-repository-helm/0.0.1<\/bundle>\n    <\/feature>'     ${NEXUS_HOME}/system/org/sonatype/nexus/assemblies/nexus-core-feature/${NEXUS_VERSION}/nexus-core-feature-${NEXUS_VERSION}-features.xml
 ---> Running in f79d0a7bbc87
sed: can't read /opt/sonatype/nexus/system/org/sonatype/nexus/assemblies/nexus-core-feature//nexus-core-feature--features.xml: No such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c sed -e '/<feature prerequisite/i\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ <feature prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-repository-helm<\/feature>' -e '/<\/features>/i \ \ \ \ <feature name="nexus-repository-helm" description="org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-repository-helm" version="0.0.1">\n        <details>org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-repository-helm<\/details>\n        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus.plugins/nexus-repository-helm/0.0.1<\/bundle>\n    <\/feature>'     ${NEXUS_HOME}/system/org/sonatype/nexus/assemblies/nexus-core-feature/${NEXUS_VERSION}/nexus-core-feature-${NEXUS_VERSION}-features.xml' returned a non-zero code: 2
ssteiner-mbp:asset-repo ssteiner$ docker build -t nexus:local .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  9.625MB
Step 1/11 : FROM alpine:3.6
 ---> 77144d8c6bdc
Step 2/11 : RUN apk add --no-cache maven git
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 06ea90323059
Step 3/11 : WORKDIR /build/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 883f7001e5e7
Step 4/11 : RUN git clone https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-repository-helm.git     && cd nexus-repository-helm     && mvn clean package
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8916c43cbca0
Step 5/11 : FROM    sonatype/nexus3
 ---> 292674e848ae
Step 6/11 : LABEL MAINTAINER=[...]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ba1dedda1d61
Step 7/11 : ARG NEXUS_VERSION=3.12.1-01
 ---> Running in d57500c9e0c7
Removing intermediate container d57500c9e0c7
 ---> 6100a60825e0
Step 8/11 : ENV SONATYPE_DIR=/opt/sonatype
 ---> Running in 33658a9a879b
Removing intermediate container 33658a9a879b
 ---> 496da8aa67b9
Step 9/11 : ENV NEXUS_HOME=${SONATYPE_DIR}/nexus   NEXUS_DATA=/nexus-data
 ---> Running in 3c57eff29800
Removing intermediate container 3c57eff29800
 ---> 6ce7595add66
Step 10/11 : COPY --from=0       /build/nexus-repository-helm/target/nexus-repository-helm-0.0.1.jar   ${NEXUS_HOME}/system/org/sonatype/nexus/plugins/nexus-repository-helm/0.0.1/nexus-repository-helm-0.0.1.jar
 ---> 4f85bde4e5eb
Step 11/11 : RUN sed -e '/<feature prerequisite/i\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ <feature prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-repository-helm<\/feature>' -e '/<\/features>/i \ \ \ \ <feature name="nexus-repository-helm" description="org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-repository-helm" version="0.0.1">\n        <details>org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-repository-helm<\/details>\n        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus.plugins/nexus-repository-helm/0.0.1<\/bundle>\n    <\/feature>'     ${NEXUS_HOME}/system/org/sonatype/nexus/assemblies/nexus-core-feature/${NEXUS_VERSION}/nexus-core-feature-${NEXUS_VERSION}-features.xml
 ---> Running in de0fe21cd88e
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<features xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.4.0" name="nexus-core-feature">
    <feature name="nexus-core-feature" description="org.sonatype.nexus.assemblies:nexus-core-feature" version="3.12.1.01">
        <details>org.sonatype.nexus.assemblies:nexus-core-feature</details>
        <feature version="3.12.1.01" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-audit-plugin</feature>
        <feature version="3.12.1.01" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-blobstore-tasks</feature>
        <feature version="3.12.1.01" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-ssl-plugin</feature>
        <feature version="3.12.1.01" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-coreui-plugin</feature>
        <feature version="3.12.1.01" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-repository-httpbridge</feature>
        <feature version="3.12.1.01" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-repository-maven</feature>
        <feature version="3.12.1.01" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-repository-npm</feature>
        <feature version="3.12.1.01" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-repository-raw</feature>
        <feature version="3.12.1.01" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-restore-maven</feature>
        <feature version="3.12.1.01" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-blobstore-s3</feature>
        <feature version="3.12.1.01" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-restore-npm</feature>
        <feature version="3.12.1.01" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-script-plugin</feature>
        <feature version="3.12.1.01" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-task-log-cleanup</feature>
        <feature prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-repository-helm</feature>
        <feature prerequisite="true" dependency="false">wrap</feature>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus/nexus-core/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus/nexus-supportzip-api/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus/nexus-email/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-email/1.5</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.sun.mail/javax.mail/1.5.6</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus/nexus-repository/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus/nexus-capability/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus/nexus-mime/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.tika/tika-core/1.14</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus/nexus-blobstore/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus/nexus-blobstore-api/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus/nexus-blobstore-file/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.4</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:com.squareup/tape/1.2.3</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus/nexus-httpclient/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus/nexus-elasticsearch/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus.bundles/org.sonatype.nexus.bundles.elasticsearch/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-cbor/2.9.2</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-smile/2.9.2</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml/2.9.2</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.18</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.hdrhistogram/HdrHistogram/2.1.6</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:com.vividsolutions/jts/1.13</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.ning/compress-lzf/1.0.2</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:io.netty/netty/3.10.6.Final</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus/nexus-selector/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-jexl3/3.0</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.james/apache-mime4j/0.6</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus/nexus-script/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.ivy/ivy/2.3.0</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus/nexus-ssl/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:org.apache.geronimo.framework/geronimo-crypto/2.2.1</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus/nexus-webhooks/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus/nexus-quartz/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus/nexus-scheduling/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs/jboss-jaxrs-api_2.0_spec/1.0.1.Beta1</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs-services/3.1.3.Final</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation/jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec/1.0.0.Final</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:net.jcip/jcip-annotations/1.0</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus/nexus-thread/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.2</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.2.2</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:c3p0/c3p0/0.9.1.1</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-compress/1.16.1</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.objenesis/objenesis/2.2</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.tukaani/xz/1.8</bundle>
    </feature>
    <feature name="nexus-audit-plugin" description="org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-audit-plugin" version="3.12.1.01">
        <details>org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-audit-plugin</details>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus.plugins/nexus-audit-plugin/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus/nexus-audit/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus/nexus-webhooks/3.12.1-01</bundle>
    </feature>
    <feature name="nexus-blobstore-tasks" description="org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-blobstore-tasks" version="3.12.1.01">
        <details>org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-blobstore-tasks</details>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus.plugins/nexus-blobstore-tasks/3.12.1-01</bundle>
    </feature>
    <feature name="nexus-ssl-plugin" description="org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-ssl-plugin" version="3.12.1.01">
        <details>org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-ssl-plugin</details>
        <feature prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-repository-helm</feature>
        <feature prerequisite="true" dependency="false">wrap</feature>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus.plugins/nexus-ssl-plugin/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus/nexus-ssl/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus/nexus-crypto/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:org.apache.geronimo.framework/geronimo-crypto/2.2.1</bundle>
    </feature>
    <feature name="nexus-coreui-plugin" description="org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-coreui-plugin" version="3.12.1.01">
        <details>org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-coreui-plugin</details>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus.plugins/nexus-coreui-plugin/3.12.1-01</bundle>
    </feature>
    <feature name="nexus-repository-httpbridge" description="org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-repository-httpbridge" version="3.12.1.01">
        <details>org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-repository-httpbridge</details>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus.plugins/nexus-repository-httpbridge/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.3.2</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:commons-io/commons-io/2.4</bundle>
    </feature>
    <feature name="nexus-repository-maven" description="org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-repository-maven" version="3.12.1.01">
        <details>org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-repository-maven</details>
        <feature prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-repository-helm</feature>
        <feature prerequisite="true" dependency="false">wrap</feature>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus.plugins/nexus-repository-maven/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:org.apache.maven/maven-model/3.3.3</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:org.codehaus.plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.24</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:org.apache.maven/maven-repository-metadata/3.3.3</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.eclipse.aether/aether-api/1.0.2.v20150114</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.eclipse.aether/aether-util/1.0.2.v20150114</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.eclipse.aether/aether-spi/1.0.2.v20150114</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.maven.indexer/indexer-reader/5.1.2-816025a</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:org.apache.maven.archetype/archetype-catalog/2.4</bundle>
    </feature>
    <feature name="nexus-repository-npm" description="org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-repository-npm" version="3.12.1.01">
        <details>org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-repository-npm</details>
        <feature prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-repository-helm</feature>
        <feature prerequisite="true" dependency="false">wrap</feature>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus.plugins/nexus-repository-npm/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-compress/1.16.1</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.objenesis/objenesis/2.2</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:se.sawano.java/alphanumeric-comparator/1.4.1</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-joda/2.9.2</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.9.2</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.9.2</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:joda-time/joda-time/2.9.5</bundle>
    </feature>
    <feature name="nexus-repository-raw" description="org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-repository-raw" version="3.12.1.01">
        <details>org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-repository-raw</details>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus.plugins/nexus-repository-raw/3.12.1-01</bundle>
    </feature>
    <feature name="nexus-restore-maven" description="org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-restore-maven" version="3.12.1.01">
        <details>org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-restore-maven</details>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus.plugins/nexus-restore-maven/3.12.1-01</bundle>
    </feature>
    <feature name="nexus-restore-npm" description="org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-restore-npm" version="3.12.1.01">
        <details>org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-restore-npm</details>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus.plugins/nexus-restore-npm/3.12.1-01</bundle>
    </feature>
    <feature name="nexus-script-plugin" description="org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-script-plugin" version="3.12.1.01">
        <details>org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-script-plugin</details>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus.plugins/nexus-script-plugin/3.12.1-01</bundle>
    </feature>
    <feature name="nexus-task-log-cleanup" description="org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-task-log-cleanup" version="3.12.1.01">
        <details>org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-task-log-cleanup</details>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus.plugins/nexus-task-log-cleanup/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:commons-io/commons-io/2.4</bundle>
    </feature>
    <feature name="nexus-blobstore-s3" description="org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-blobstore-s3" version="3.12.1.01">
        <details>org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-blobstore-s3</details>
        <feature prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-repository-helm</feature>
        <feature prerequisite="true" dependency="false">wrap</feature>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus.plugins/nexus-blobstore-s3/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.codahale.metrics/metrics-annotation/3.0.2</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus/nexus-extdirect/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus/nexus-analytics-api/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus/nexus-servlet/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus/nexus-guice-servlet/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:eu.bitwalker/UserAgentUtils/1.19</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus/nexus-validation/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.1.2.Final</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging/3.1.3.GA</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.fasterxml/classmate/1.0.0</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus/nexus-webresources-api/3.12.1-01</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.google.code.gson/gson/2.3.1</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.3.2</bundle>
    </feature>
    <feature name="nexus-repository-helm" description="org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-repository-helm" version="0.0.1">
        <details>org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-repository-helm</details>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus.plugins/nexus-repository-helm/0.0.1</bundle>
    </feature>
</features>
Removing intermediate container de0fe21cd88e
 ---> 740b5256c0f0
Successfully built 740b5256c0f0
Successfully tagged nexus:local
```

Then afterwards, an exec session into the running container and doing a `cat` of the file shows the original contents (I don't have space to post the full file, but trust me, it's unmodified). What am I missing?

Comment: I use `sed -e` to search and replace to standard out and `sed -i` to search and replace in-place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second invocation of `sed`, i.e. the one that is to modify `${NEXUS_HOME}/system/org/sonatype/nexus/assemblies/nexus-core-feature/${NEXUS_VERSION}/nexus-core-feature-${NEXUS_VERSION}-features.xml`, appears to be **missing the `-i`/`--in-place` flag**, leading to the output being written to standard out rather than to the input file.

It can be a helpful practice to specify options that do not require parameters before those that do, whenever the order of the options does not change their effect.